# Migrate web2py project to a newer version

Tags: python, web2py, migrate

I got an extensive web2py project which is currently still running on web2py 2.0.9 .
I would like to migrate it to the newest version 2.14.6 to get the more extensive bootstrap options and more styling possibilities.

What would be the things I would most likely run into and what would be the best course of action?

Comment: create a virtual enviroment for 2.14.6 and 2.0.9 ? after that you can run you code in both version and test is that compatible for latest version [python venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: I did but mostly the bootstrap CSS came out all wrong. It's not about Python 3, i don't think web2py runs in python3 yet. It's about the default CSS and bootstrap changes.

Comment: There is no need to upgrade web2py in order to change your front-end UI. You can style your app however you like with whatever CSS and front-end framework you like. web2py provides a scaffolding app with a basic default front-end, but you can replace it, and you certainly don't need an upgraded version of the framework to do so.

Comment: Still one of the things i ran in to at the first attempt was that things like the navigation bar were not styled because of changing class names etc.